# Find and replace hostname to ip address within a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, cut

I have a huge file with about 12300 lines that look something similar to this.

```
001.domain.com=001.somedomain.com:10001
002.domain.com=002.somedomain.com:10002
003.domain.com=003.somedomain.com:10003
```

I want the file to look like this when it is done

```
001.domain.com=IP_Address_of_001.somedomain.com:10001
002.domain.com=IP_Address_of_002.somedomain.com:10002
003.domain.com=IP_Address_of_003.somedomain.com:10003
```

So basically I need to find and replace the hostname after the = signs with the ip address.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: How do we know what is the IP address to use for each domain?

Comment: `sed` can easily process the substitutions you need, the question here is what is the source of the IP address? DNS or a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This uses sed to extract the hostname, then uses dig to get its IP, then uses sed again for the replace. It outputs the replacements to a new file:

```
$ while read line; do 
    hostname=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/.*=\(.*\):.*/\1/g")
    ip=$(dig +short $hostname | head -n1)
    echo "$line" | sed "s/\(.*=\).*\(:.*\)/\1${ip}\2/g"
done < file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar option by using `host` instead of `dig`:

```
$ cat filename.txt | while read line; do 
IP=$(host $(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1) | grep -m1 "has address" | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev)
echo $line | sed "s/\(.*=\).*\(:.*\)/\1${IP}\2/g"
done
```

The parsing which takes the hostname may be substituted by `awk`:

```
$ cat filename.txt | while read line; do 
IP=$(host $(echo $line | cut -d= -f1) | awk -F'[ ]' '/has address/ {print $4;exit;}')
echo $line | sed "s/\(.*=\).*\(:.*\)/\1${IP}\2/g"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'[:=]' '{ cmd="host "$2"| cut -d\" \" -f4"; cmd |getline $2; 
    print $1"="$2":"$3; close(cmd) }' infile
```

We set a shell command `host $2"| cut -d\" \" -f4` to a variable called `cmd`. Then with `cmd |getline $2` the `awk` execute the command saves the result into  second field value itself from the result of `cmd` we open it [Using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe), next we print the columns, then we need to close the command we opened, and we used [`close(cmd)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) here.

Or replace `host` with `dig +short` will make the command short:

```
awk -F'[:=]' '{ cmd="dig +short "$2; cmd |getline $2; 
    print $1"="$2":"$3; close(cmd) }' infile
```